# Name and interpretation of the $\stackrel{d}{=}$ symbol.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Context**: I have the following statement which uses the symbol  $\stackrel{d}{=}$.

Let X be a Random Variable, and let $X'$ be an RV that is independent of $X$ and $X'\stackrel{d}{=}X$.

We call the Random Variable
$$X^s = X −X'$$
symmetrized X.

Comment: It looks like it might mean that $X'$ and $X$ have the same distribution. By the way, are you sure that $X$ should be independent from itself?

Comment: There was a typo. It is actually $X'$. My bad.

Comment: Equality in distribution.

Comment: Think about dices. If $X$ is the result of a dice, and $X'$ is the result of another dice, they have the same distribution, and they are independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\overset d =$ means equal in distribution. More precise, let $(\Omega_1 , \mathcal F _1 , \Bbb P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2 , \mathcal F _2 , \Bbb P_2)$ be two probability spaces and $X_i:\Omega_i \to \Bbb R$ be a random variable on $\Omega_i$.
The pushforward measure on $(\Bbb R , \mathcal B (\Bbb R))$
$$\Bbb P_i \circ X_i^{-1}$$
is called the distribution (or law) of $X_i$.
Then we say $X_1$ is equal in distribution to $X_2$ (write $X_1 \overset d = X_2$) if
$$\Bbb P_1 \circ X_1^{-1} = \Bbb P_2 \circ X_2^{-1}.$$
Note that  for this definition, $X_1$ and $X_2$ do not need to be defined on the same probability space.

There are also the following symbols (meaning the same as $\overset d =$) in use:

$\sim$

$\overset{\mathcal{D}}{=}$ ($\mathcal D$ for "distribution")

$\overset{\mathcal{L}}{=}$ ($\mathcal L $ for "law", fortunately seldom used)

Comment: The symbol $\stackrel{\text{law}}{=}$ is also used in some literature. It seems like everyone is using whichever version that is most aesthetically appealing to them. (Thankfully enough, however, at least using the mere equality sign $=$ to denote an equality in distribution seems very much depreciated these days.)